# How to normalize just particular columns, and leave others intact with Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have the following sample code which I understand, normalizes the given tree columns:

```
adapt_data = np.array([[0., 7., 4.],
                       [2., 9., 6.],
                       [0., 7., 4.],
                       [2., 9., 6.]], dtype='float32')

input_data = np.array([[0., 7., 4.]], dtype='float32')
layer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1)
layer.adapt(adapt_data)
output = layer(input_data)
```

However I would like to leave some columns intact. (in my input data for those columns already are between [-1.0, 1.0] mean and variance is not guaranteed, but I would like not to touch that data.

**Question**

Is it possible to have a normalization layer which processes the input data as a whole, and only normalizes just certain columns, leaving others intact, or do I have to preprocess my data column by column?

Comment: You can use a `mask like` tensor to preserve some specific column you want, just like `output = layer(input_data)*mask+input_data*(1.0-mask)`, where mask is  a `0.0 and 1.0` vector. But this method has extra overhead, depending on the specific data distribution. If want no extra cost, you still have to calculate column by column since there is no layernorm operator that  support native `mask`.